# Upload and clearing selected filename after file upload

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

When using the Upload component, after succesfull file upload the file name stays in the Upload field. Is there a way how to clear it after upload?

Comment: Please share your code. Can't reproduce your case on my computer. http://pastebin.com/7s34k1jG

Comment: Just tried your simple example several times on different app parts. Doesnt work for me. Upload control still keep the file name after upload completed.

Comment: Can you upload a video(gif) with this bug?

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue. Were you able to fix it? If so can you let me know what was the fix?